# Repeatedly append to string haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi i'm new to haskell and am unsure how to approach it. I have the following code so far

```
ask :: String -> IO ()
ask prompt =
  do
  putStrLn prompt
  line <- getLine
  if line == ""
    then ask "please try again"
    else putStrLn ("you said: " ++ reverse line)

main :: IO ()
main =
  do
  ask "please say something"
```

i'm trying to make it so that when someone presses enter without typing anything, the repeated prompt will have an extra “!” at the end. So every time it repeats it adds an additional "!"

Example Output:
please say something

please try again!

please try again!!

please try again!!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing *one* prompt to `ask`, pass *all* your prompts, in the form of an infinite list generated by `iterate`:

```
ask :: [String] -> IO ()
ask (p:ps) =
  do
  putStrLn p
  line <- getLine
  if line == ""
    then ask ps
    else putStrLn ("you said: " ++ reverse line)

main :: IO ()
main =
  do
  ask ("please say something" : iterate (++"!") "please try again")
```

Each call to `ask` prints the first prompt in its input and passes the rest on to the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a counter to your method, like:

```
ask :: String -> IO ()
ask = ask' 1

ask' :: Int -> String -> IO ()
ask' n prompt = do
  putStrLn prompt
  line <- getLine
  if null line
    then ask' (n+1) ("please try again" ++ replicate n '!')
    else putStrLn ("you said: " ++ reverse line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to contribute with another approach.

You want to make two actions.

- One is to print the given string in reverse
- the other is to handling the error, printing a new error message each time.

Let's define this two actions:

```
-- This prints the given line backwards
putReverse :: String -> IO ()
putReverse line = putStrLn $ "you said: " ++ reverse line

-- Given an error message an a IO action, prints the message an execute the IO
askAgain :: String -> IO () -> IO ()
askAgain errorMessage io = putStrLn errorMessage >> io
```

The `ask` function recives as input the desired error message. it asks for a line and handles each case. When calling `askAgain` the io action is the same `ask` function but with new error messsage

```
ask :: String -> IO ()
ask errorMessage = do
  line <- getLine
  if line == ""
    then askAgain errorMessage $ ask (errorMessage ++ "!") -- here is where you update the error message
    else putReverse line

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "please say something" -- optionally this prompt can but an argument for ask function. Try to refactor as an exercise!!
  ask "please try again"
```